# Setter method not working for a property of a UITableViewCell Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to get a table to display a list of names and ranks.  In each cell, I want to have 2 UILabels as subviews--one UILabel to display the rank and one UILabel to display the name.

I've created a UITableViewCell subclass with two properties as follows:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property UILabel* rankLabel;
@property UILabel* nameLabel;
```

I haven't added anything to the .m implementation file of MyTableView other than @synthesize for each of the properties.  The rest of the implementation file is just what xCode gives you when you create a UITableViewCell subclass.

Then, in the masterViewController that contains the table, I have the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Person *object = _objects[indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.height, 0, cell.frame.size.width - cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.height)];
    cell.nameLabel.text = object.name;
    [cell addSubview:cell.nameLabel];

    NSString* rankString = [object.rank stringValue];
    cell.rankLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.height)];
    cell.rankLabel.text = rankString;
    [cell addSubview:cell.rankLabel];
}
```

When I run this in debug, it gets to the first line where I set cell.nameLabel and alloc it, and throws the following error:

```
[UITableViewCell setNameLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108fa64c0
```

Really don't understand why the setNameLabel method should be having problems here.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you not using storyboards at all? Or just not for this particular cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to tell you the exact problem. It doesn't say `[MyTableViewCell setNameLabel:]` it says `[UITableViewCell setNameLabel:]` you've probably forgot to change the class for the cell in your storyboard to `MyTableViewCell`...

Edit: No, he's not using storyboard, but the crash obviously seems related to the cell being of the wrong class.

Edit: Yes he was, or at least Xcode was doing it for him.

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard for this program, though thanks for calling my attention to that difference... I'm looking back at the code now to see if I can figure out why that difference is there.

Comment: Cheers! Should have noticed that you do it in code. It seems odd as you're clearly setting the identifier...

Comment: Nice, you were right.  I was doing everything programmatically, so figured I wouldn't have to deal with the storyboard at all, but the basic storyboard that XCode gives you as default needed to have the cell type changed over to MyTableViewCell just as you said.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! "A friend of mine" has made the same mistake once or twice. ;-)